# Site design updates are live!

Tags: discussion, design

**A design update is now live!**

Most of the changes are not visible; these tweaks go along with recent updates that were made to Stack Overflow:

- We moved the site's CSS to a newly refactored LESS system, so that it's easier for us to fix SE network CSS bugs globally and launch new features in the future.
- We updated the graphics to SVG for retina support.
- We've fixed a LOT of obscure bugs that arose when new features were not thoroughly tested across the entire network.
- We have launched a shiny new user profile!

Visually it should "feel" the same as the old site with slight layout adjustments.

This update should retro-actively fix most of the old design bugs. If you see any new bugs, or old ones not yet fixed, please post an answer here to let us know!

Comment: Within the next few days.

Comment: Or perhaps today.

Answer (score 8):

The favorite star noticeably moves to the right when it's enabled.

When greyed out, it's aligned with the voting arrows.

[image: before]

When yellow, it is not aligned:

[image: after]

The screenshots are from this meta post; the main site shows the same behavior.

Comment: Good catch. We'll fix it.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers, the upvote normal distribution also shifts slightly to the right when clicked.

Comment: Yeah, the sprite got shifted. Fixing soon.

Comment: This issue should be fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

The colour choices for normal links and visited links in the hot network questions is counter-intuitive, as visited link get emphasised instead of de-emphasised:

[image]

Comment: I just pushed a fix. This should go live on our next production server build.